# Spring+TestNG: packages not scanned for annotations

Tags: spring, ant, testng, spring-test

I have a simple (ant based) test based on `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests`. I get an error complaining no suitable bean found for auto wiring.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userSessionDao")
private UserSessionDAO userSessionDao;
```

The DAO:

```
@Repository("userSessionDao")
public class UserSessionDAOImpl extends
    AbstractGenericDAOImpl<UserSession, Long> implements UserSessionDAO {
/**
 * 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private XLogger logger = XLoggerFactory.getXLogger(UserSessionDAOImpl.class
        .getName());

}
```

I have the following in the config.xml: 
    < context:component-scan base-package="com.blah" />

Am I missing a step to make component-scan kick in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah.*" />`

Also, check that `UserSessionDAO` is an autowired candidate.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the DAO. Tried with com.blah.* but didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like UserSessionDAOImpl it is in somewhere where Spring cannot see it. Are you sure UserSessionDAOImpl is under com.blah package?

Comment: The package is correct, my classpath settings were wrong. :-)